# Using Robust SE's for plot_models from package gee

Tags: r, sjplot

I noticed using plot_models from package sjPlot gives confidence intervals based on the Naive standard errors. I want it to use the Robust SEs. Is there a simple fix?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, sjPlot does not support this option, however, it is planned for a forthcoming update. **sjPlot** uses the [**parameters** package](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/) to compute model parameters - if you don't mind updating the **parameters** package from GitHub (and installing the [**see** package](https://easystats.github.io/see/)), you can already use this feature:

```r
library(parameters)
library(gee)

data(warpbreaks)
model <- gee(breaks ~ tension, id = wool, data = warpbreaks)
#> Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
#> running glm to get initial regression estimate
#> (Intercept)    tensionM    tensionH 
#>    36.38889   -10.00000   -14.72222

mp <- model_parameters(model)

mp
#> Parameter   | Coefficient |   SE |          95% CI |     z | df |      p
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept) |       36.39 | 2.80 | [ 30.90, 41.88] | 12.99 | 51 | < .001
#> tension [M] |      -10.00 | 3.96 | [-17.76, -2.24] | -2.53 | 51 | 0.015 
#> tension [H] |      -14.72 | 3.96 | [-22.48, -6.96] | -3.72 | 51 | < .001

plot(mp)
```

[image]

```r
mp <- model_parameters(model, robust = TRUE)

mp
#> Parameter   | Coefficient |   SE |          95% CI |     z | df |      p
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept) |       36.39 | 5.77 | [ 25.07, 47.71] |  6.30 | 51 | < .001
#> tension [M] |      -10.00 | 7.46 | [-24.63,  4.63] | -3.94 | 51 | 0.186 
#> tension [H] |      -14.72 | 3.73 | [-22.04, -7.41] | -1.34 | 51 | < .001

plot(mp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: But I am using plot_models for comparing multiple regressions. Is there a fix for that function similar to what you provided? (If not, when might it be updated?) Thanks.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought you referred to `plot_model()`. I must see if implementing robust standard errors is done easily...

Comment: Any luck? Our team is hoping to use such plots in writing a manuscript.

Comment: Hi Daniel, just checking in if there's any progress on this.

Comment: I think that if you update parameters from CRAN, it should now also work for `plot_models()`. However, there was an issue with lme4 models, which is fixed in the current GitHub version.

Comment: Hmm I reinstalled parameters and restarted R but still getting Naive CI's in `plot_models()`.

Comment: True, but now I have fixed the issue in _parameetrs. I plan to submit an update of parameters within the days, so once it's updated, it should work.

Comment: Tried again but no luck - did you end up updating parameters? Thanks,

Comment: Hi Daniel, just following up to see if an update is still in the works.

Comment: I think it should work now after updating parameters and sjPlot from _GitHub_. CRAN submission is planned by the end of March.